# Native C/C++ code on an Android platform

Tags: c++, android, native

I have two questions regarding native C/C++ on Android platforms:

1. Is it possible for device manufactures to develop native C++ applications on an Android platform?
2. How can I develop my own native C++ application / library that has an upper layer Java front-end / API on an Android platform?

Answer (score 10):

Official announcement and download links:

> Introducing Android 1.5 NDK, Release 1
> Posted by David Turner on 25 June 2009 at 10:30 AM
>
> Many of you have been asking for the ability to call into native code from your Android applications. I'm glad to announce that developers can now download the Android Native Development Kit from the Android developer site.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/06/introducing-android-15-ndk-release-1.html

Answer (score 2):

this blog entry explains how to do native programming on android:
http://rxwen.blogspot.com/2009/11/native-programming-on-android.html 
hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it's not supported.  Native code requirements may vary significantly from one Android system to the next; unless you are working on very low-level infrastructure, it is best to go the Java-source-to-Dalvik-VM route for portability.  And of course, you'll likely be tied to the very phone you wrote your native code for, though if you integrate it into Android it may be accepted and maintained for all platforms the system intends to support.

Comment: Terribily inaccurate. Native code works on any supporting it phone, just like Java code

Comment: @PiotrK, I'm not sure what you mean.  Android's Dalvik VM (which, yes, uses Java to represent source code, but isn't actually Java) is of course native code.  But it will be built specifically for the phone's CPU and architecture/platform.  Nothing says Android *MUST* run on an ARM, or which model(s) of ARM it is allowed to run on. Therefore, compilation requirements depend on hardware implementation. "It's not supported", as I said, for applications uploaded to the Android markets.  That said, LLVM would solve that problem nicely; not sure why Google didn't do that instead of what they do do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a device manufacturer, of course. You can essentially do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

This article explains it quite well: http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/09/android-invoke-jni-based-methods-bridging-cc-and-java/

Answer (score 0):

Google has released a Native Development Kit (NDK) (according to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5whfaLH1-E at 00:07:30).

Hopefully the information will be updated on the google groups page (http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk), as it says it hasn't been released yet.

I'm not sure where to get a simple download for it, but I've heard that you can get a copy of the NDK from Google's Git repository under the donut branch.

Answer (score -2):

Well Android tend to have a normal Linux in the bottom, 
so writing Linux apps should be possible if you only can get the code in there...
(but often you can't, since the phone is locked at that level)

So the answer would be:

1. Yes, but it depends
2. Yes, but it depends